# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: REPORT Table is not mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a simple API that expects three parameters and sends a response back, whenever I try to pass the three parameters I end up with an error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: REPORTS
> is not mapped [SELECT e FROM REPORTS e WHERE e.country =
> :country AND e.projectId = :projectId AND e.code = :code]

The Model class

```
@Entity(name = "REPORTS")
@Table(name = "REPORTS")
public class DashboardModel {
    public String Country;
    public String Project;
    public String HtmlContent;
    public String FileName;
    public String Code;
    public String TeamLead;
    public String Team;
    public DateTime CreateDate;
    public DateTime UpdateDate;

//boiler plate code
```

My Controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/report/reportsheet")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getReportSheet(@RequestParam("country") String country,
                                                      @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId,
                                                      @RequestParam("clusterNumber") String clusterNumber){
        String report = dashboardService.getReport(country,projectId,clusterNumber);
        //String report_ = wallboardService.getStateReportLabelByCountryProjectAndType(country,projectId,reportType);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(report);
```

My Service

```
 public String getReport(String country,String projectId,String code){

        TypedQuery<DashboardModel> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT e FROM REPORTS e WHERE e.country = :country AND e.projectId = :projectId AND e.code = :clusterNumber" , DashboardModel.class);

        List<DashboardModel> dashboard = query
                .setParameter("country", country)
                .setParameter("projectId", projectId)
                .setParameter("clusterNumber", code)
                .getResultList();

        return String.valueOf(dashboard);

    }
```

How should I map the table correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the entity is not in a package that is scanned by Spring Boot. Here is an article about this: https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use entity class names like `DashboardModel` in the JPQL and a table name `REPORTS` in the SQL.

The second parameter `DashboardModel.class` in the `createQuery()` is not related to entity class name in the `SELECT` clause.
You can just use `createQuery(jpql)` with one parameter, but that method returns a `List` without element type. So what the second parameter `DashboardModel.class` for.

You don't need to specify table name here `@Entity(name = "REPORTS")`

just `@Entity`